# HTML, Trouble redirecting to page

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to HTML and coding. I've been learning in school and practicing what I learn on a little "website". I'm trying to make an about me page by using the code line
`<a href="abouthawkedx.htm">About HAWkEdx</a>`
I have the file abouthawkedx.htm on my desktop and when I try to click on it in firefox it says it can't be found. 
Thanks

Comment: Where did you launch the address <a href="abouthawkedx.htm">About HAWkEdx</a> from, an address bar? Have you added the Header <! Doctype ... like TomC posted? If you lauched it from another page, try "./abouthawkedx.htm"

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic elements within an htm or html file as follows;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p><a href="abouthawkedx.htm">About HAWkEdx</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then save this file as index.htm or whatever. It must be in the same directory as your abouhawkedx.htm file or you will need to specify the path/location to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your abouthawkedx.htm file in the same directory where all pages of website you save or just give whole path of abouthawkedx.htm where your abouthawkedx.htm is stored. As you say your file is on desktop so use code line like:

```
<a href="c:/users/user_name/your_file name">About HAWkEdx</a>
```

For more information about file path in html please refer bellow link:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp